# How to properly install mosquitto (mqtt broker) and how to setup MQTT node-red?

Tags: installation, windows-installation, openssl, mqtt

I have been messing around with node-red and some arduino stuff, but now I'm trying to connect to my arduino both to use it to receive and send data content.

But I'm having no luck on installing mosquitto on my machine, I've tried multiple different solutions I found on the internet but none helped me.

Most of them said that only the x86 version would work, but not even that.

Can anyone give me a walkthrough on how to properly install latest mosquitto version on Windows 10 x64 and maybe how to connect it to the MQTT service on node-red?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this over and over and both my coworker and I agree that this is the best method ***(by far)***.

Getting all of the dlls right is a pain in the butt and most sites that will help you are geared for Linux and not Windows... SSOOOOooooo.. take advantage of having Linux built in to Windows.

*I am assuming that you are trying to develop* and ***not run a server 24/7***.  If you are running it as a server, there are things you can do to make this run at all times.

1. Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
2. Install Debian9 or Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store (they are free)
3. Use the Linux package manager to install and run Mosquitto and or node-red

From now on, you can use Linux downloads and instructions for anything like this.  You don't need to use a ported copy with poor documentation.

My server is running in WSL while I write MQTT code in c# using visual studio against it.  It works great.

I originally got the idea from [here](http://www.abrandao.com/2018/03/running-mosquitto-mqtt-on-windows-10-super-easy/).  It has more detailed instructions.